# Android resource linking failed error after updating android studio

Tags: android, kotlin, resources

I just updated android studio, and suddenly my app wouldn't run anymore showing this error:

```
D:\my_projects\android-kotlin\Android-MVP-2.0\app\src\main\res\values\attr.xml:5:5-13:25: AAPT: error: resource attr/arrayContent (aka com.app.finfirst:attr/arrayContent) not found.
```

the error is pointing to this resource file I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>


    <declare-styleable name="BulletTextView">
        <attr name="arrayContent" />
        <attr name="textSize" />
        <attr name="textColor" />
        <attr name="starGapWidth" />
        <attr name="starRadius" />
        <attr name="mmfLineSpacing" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

The error is showing on every `attr` item I have in the file. Please note that before the update the project was running normally. I also tried to update the gradle but the error is still poping-up.

Edit: from what I've seen in similar questions, this error occur when you have a syntax error in the xml file but I don't have any errors in this file, so what might be causing this problem

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a similar issue to the one detailed here https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-android/issues/479. Are you perhaps missing a format declaration?

Also might be worth doing file>invalidate caches and restart after updating android studio